# How do I get the_time as one string of numbers in wordpress?

Tags: php

I'm using wordpress. I remember messing with the code of `<?php the_time('d.m.y') ?>` and getting something like "2011161457" (2011 16-1 4:57) I don't remember how I did it. I want just the numbers anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/date) man page. Wordpress's `time_time()` is basically just a wrapper around that and uses the exact same formating options.